# Add a key value pair into to the Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

The following object i am getting as a query result. i want to append `key3 : value3` after each `key2 : value2`. I looped the result Object and tried to add 
a status by something similar to this `loopedItem.status = "1"` but it is not worked for me can anyone help me out.

```
[
  { 
   key1 : [
            {
             key1.1 : value1.1 
            },
            {
             key1.2 : value1.2
            }
           ],
   key2 : value2
  },
  { 
   key1 : [
            {
             key1.1 : value1.1 
            },
            {
             key1.2 : value1.2
            }
           ],
   key2 : value2
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain more!

Comment: Add the code you tried to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var x = [
      { 
       key1 : [
                {
                 "key1.1" : "value1.1" 
                },
                {
                 "key1.2" : "value1.2"
                }
               ],
       key2 : "value2"
      },
      { 
       key1 : [
                {
                 "key1.1" : "value1.1" 
                },
                {
                 "key1.2" : "value1.2"
                }
               ],
       key2 : "value2"
      }
    ]

for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
 var eachItem = x[i];
 eachItem['key3'] = 'value3';  // adds a key with value value3
}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
objs = [
    {
        "key1" : [
            {
                "key1.1" : "value1.1"
            },
            {
                "key1.2" : "value1.2"
            }
        ],
        "key2" : "value2"
    },
    {
        "key1" : [
            {
                "key1.1" : "value1.1"
            },
            {
                "key1.2" : "value1.2"
            }
        ],
        "key2" : "value2"
    }
]


for (ele in objs) {
    objs[ele]["status"] = "1"
}
for (ele in objs) {
    console.log(objs[ele])
    console.log("\n" + "--------------------")


}
```